# Sorting CSV files using date in file name

Tags: python, csv, sorting, date

I have a list of CSV files that are in a file on my google drive. The main file is called all_files and the CSV files are listed like below.

`all_files`

```
['/content/drive/MyDrive/COVID-19/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_daily_reports/11-07-2020.csv',
 '/content/drive/MyDrive/COVID-19/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_daily_reports/11-12-2020.csv',
 '/content/drive/MyDrive/COVID-19/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_daily_reports/07-28-2020.csv',
 '/content/drive/MyDrive/COVID-19/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_daily_reports/03-16-2020.csv',
 '/content/drive/MyDrive/COVID-19/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_daily_reports/07-18-2020.csv']
```

I am trying to find a way to sort these files based on the date in the file name (ex. 03-16-2020) (basically Jan 1 to latest file date) and return the sorted list of files while retaining all file data. Im not sure if I should sort them as a string because the resulting sort would not carry the file data with it.

Thanks for any help in advance

Comment: Do you have a list of strings as indicated, or a list of `open()`ed file handles, or something else?

Comment: Just a list of strings. Files are imported using glob.glob and the data path is assigned to all_files. When all_files is run the output is all the files names listed exactly as they are above, just more of them.

Comment: Ah okay, so by "would not carry the file data with it" you mean it doesn't have the original filename? Luckily `sort[ed]` has the `key=` keyword for exactly that sort of thing

Comment: Yes I believe that will do the trick

Comment: I posted some code below for you to have a look

Comment: Can you explain the sentence "Im not sure if I should sort them as a string because the resulting sort would not carry the file data with it."? Since your dates are all in 2020, and the month figure before the day, and every month and day has exactly two digits, sorting the list naively would produce the correct order...

Comment: Basically saying that since these are file names that follow a data path back to my drive any modification of the file name has to still work when the file is called after being sorted. So if the file name is stripped down to just the date in this case for sorting the file has to be able to be called later on using the stripped down file name.

Answer (score 1):

This solution builds a `(year, month, day)` tuple for each filename `fn` and then just uses Python's built-in sorting which will compare a tuple front-to-back

```py
# gets 'mm-dd-yyyy' part of filename string
get_date = lambda fn: fn.split('/')[-1].split('.')[0].split('-')

# actual sorting using tuples
sorted(all_files, key=
        lambda fn: (get_date(fn)[2], get_date(fn)[0], get_date(fn)[1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your dates are all in 2020, and the month figure before the day, and every month and day has exactly two digits, and the only difference between two filenames is the date: sorting the list of strings naively would produce the correct order.

In general though, to correctly parse a date, I recommend using `datetime.datetime.strptime`. You can supply it as the `key` argument to `sorted` or `list.sort`:

```py
import datetime

allfiles = [
  '/content/drive/MyDrive/COVID-19/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_daily_reports/11-07-2020.csv',
  '/content/drive/MyDrive/COVID-19/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_daily_reports/11-12-2020.csv',
  '/content/drive/MyDrive/COVID-19/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_daily_reports/07-28-2020.csv',
  '/content/drive/MyDrive/COVID-19/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_daily_reports/03-16-2020.csv',
  '/content/drive/MyDrive/COVID-19/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_daily_reports/07-18-2020.csv'
]

naively_sorted = sorted(allfiles)

sorted_by_date = sorted(allfiles,
                        key=lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x[-14:-4], '%m-%d-%Y'))

print(naively_sorted)
print(sorted_by_date)

# ['/content/drive/MyDrive/COVID-19/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_daily_reports/03-16-2020.csv', '/content/drive/MyDrive/COVID-19/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_daily_reports/07-18-2020.csv', '/content/drive/MyDrive/COVID-19/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_daily_reports/07-28-2020.csv', '/content/drive/MyDrive/COVID-19/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_daily_reports/11-07-2020.csv', '/content/drive/MyDrive/COVID-19/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_daily_reports/11-12-2020.csv']
# ['/content/drive/MyDrive/COVID-19/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_daily_reports/03-16-2020.csv', '/content/drive/MyDrive/COVID-19/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_daily_reports/07-18-2020.csv', '/content/drive/MyDrive/COVID-19/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_daily_reports/07-28-2020.csv', '/content/drive/MyDrive/COVID-19/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_daily_reports/11-07-2020.csv', '/content/drive/MyDrive/COVID-19/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_daily_reports/11-12-2020.csv']
```

Note that the slice `x[-14:-4]` makes no assumption on what the beginning of the string looks like; but it does assume that the string ends with `"mm-dd-yyyy.csv"`.